# Getting "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing, unrecognized-selector

I am trying to parse a JSON object with the below code:

```
 NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];

NSArray *test = [res allValues];
@NSLog(@"%@", test);
```

I keep getting this error though I know the values look like the below:

```
2014-07-25 22:31:17.652 Application[18009:60b] (
    {
    "at_tag" = sam;
    category = 1;
    distance = "95.60";
    "hash_tag" = idk;
    uid = 1;
    vidURI = "http://server/userPosts/avfgt123.mp4";
},
    {
    "at_tag" = nick;
    category = 2;
    distance = "99.45";
    "hash_tag" = irdk;
    uid = 2;
    vidURI = "http://server/userPosts/avfg2223.mp4";
}
)
```

The whole error i get is this:

```
2014-07-25 22:33:13.829 App[18025:60b] -[__NSCFArray allValues]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10d90c0d0
2014-07-25 22:33:13.831 App[18025:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray allValues]: unrecognized selector sent to   instance 0x10d90c0d0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102477495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001021d699e objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010250865d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102468d8d ___forwarding___ + 973
4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102468938 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   App                               0x00000001000028a7 -[BFTMainViewController connectionDidFinishLoading:] + 263
6   Foundation                          0x0000000101ec736b __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 48
7   Foundation                          0x0000000101d7abdb -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 210
8   Foundation                          0x0000000101d7aaec -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 69
9   CFNetwork                           0x0000000103289637 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 107
10  CFNetwork                           0x0000000103287802 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 84
11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010241df74 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
12  CFNetwork                           0x00000001031fa3e7 _ZN19RunloopBlockContext7performEv + 133
13  CFNetwork                           0x00000001031fa217 _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 247
14  CFNetwork                           0x00000001031fa03a _ZN17MultiplexerSource8_performEPv + 72
15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102406d21 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001024065f2 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010242246f __CFRunLoopRun + 767
18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102421d83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
19  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000103cf2f04 GSEventRunModal + 161
20  UIKit                               0x0000000100d83e33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
21  App                               0x0000000100001693 main + 115
22  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001039745fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I receive the error on line:

```
NSArray *test = [res allValues];
```

This has stumped me now for quite some time, I feel it is something simple I just have never ran into this issue before and can't put my finger on it.

Comment: Your question shows that your JSON object is actually an `NSArray` of `NSDictionaries`, so `allValues` won't work, since the root object isn't a `NSDictionary`. Aka: `No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'allValues'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As my comment above suggested: Your question shows that your JSON object is actually an `NSArray` of `NSDictionaries` (I think based on the Console output, If I'm wrong let me know though), so the `allValues` method won't work, since the root object isn't an `NSDictionary`. Aka: `No visible @interface for NSArray declares the selector allValues` Try this:

```
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];

NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (NSDictionary *sub in jsonArray)
{
    [mutableArray addObjectsFromArray:[sub allValues]];
}

NSLog(@"Array is: %@",mutableArray);
```